# Joomla 2.5 component forms

Tags: php, html, joomla, checkbox, joomla2.5

I'm making a component for Joomla 2.5 and according to the [docs](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Adding_backend_actions) there is a form folder and in it a xml file:

```
<field
    name="id"
    type="hidden"
/>

<field
    name="greeting"
    type="text"
    label="COM_HELLOWORLD_HELLOWORLD_GREETING_LABEL"
    description="COM_HELLOWORLD_HELLOWORLD_GREETING_DESC"
    size="40"
    class="inputbox"
    default=""
/>
```

I need for a field to be a checkbox, so I changed type="text" to "checkbox" which is fine for adding a new entry. But with editing I need to check the value from a database to see if the checkbox is selected or not. So for example, I'll have something like this:

```
<field
    name="published"
    type="checkbox"
    label="COM_HELLOWORLD_HELLOWORLD_GREETING_LABEL"
    description="COM_HELLOWORLD_HELLOWORLD_GREETING_DESC"
    size="40"
    class="checkbox"
    default=""
/>
```

and if 'published' in the database is 1, I want the default checkbox to be selected. Is there anyway to do that? Thanks!

Comment: If the checkbox if part of an XML file, you will need to override the Field.

Comment: hope this link work for you http://docs.joomla.org/Checkbox_form_field_type

Comment: thanks for the tips..I've created a custom JFormField class but how do I get the database data into the custom field class?

Comment: Or in other words, how do I pass a value from the database to my custom JFormField class?

Comment: @Moo33 Could you also post the code of the form that how you are displaying field in the form?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the default input field in `edit.php`.This help me,it may also help you.

**For example:**

```
<?php
if($this->form->getValue('published')==1)
{
    $value=1;
}
else{
    $value=0;
}?>

<li><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('published'); ?>
<input type="text" name="jform[published]" value="<?php echo $value; ?>"  /></li>
```